# jQuery if element has class in a string of classes

Tags: jquery, this, addclass

I have dynamically created articles on my page within a `div` with an id `#content`. The articles have a long string of classes, for example

```
<article id="post-126" class="post-126 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-all-portfolio category-detached portfolio_post target">
```

and

```
<article id="post-125" class="post-125 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-all-portfolio category-terraced portfolio_post">
```

I want to add an additional class to these articles, ONLY IF it contains a certain class. For example, if the article contains the class "category-detached" (which the first one does) I want to add a class "target" to it.

Here is what I have tried, but it won't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($('#content article').hasClass('category-detached')){
    $(this).addClass('target'); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your case is window and not the element.

Just do:

```
var $elem = $('#content article');
if($elem.hasClass('category-detached')){
    $elem.addClass('target'); 
}
```

or

```
   $('#content article').addClass(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('category-detached')) return "target";
   });
```

Comment: +1, but technically, he could have that entire function wrapped in a function, and is calling it like `Method.call($)`, thus changing `this`.

Comment: @BradM True but probly an overkill but he can make use of addClass Callback as well. I liked your solution as well if OP doesn't want to do anything else in the condition your first one would be simplest way to do.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution.

```
$('#content article.category-detached').addClass('target');
```

The reason it doesn't work is because `this` isn't being referred to the context of your element.

If you switched it the following, it would modify `this` to refer to each element of your collection.

```
$('#content article').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('category-detached')){
        $(this).addClass('target'); 
    }
});
```